# Vert.x @ConsumeEvent with regex

Tags: java, regex, quarkus, vert.x

I am using this to consume events reserved to "telemetry-feed-1". I am using "io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent" with quarkus. I want to use regEx like "telemetry-feed-.*" to reserve any channel that start with "telemetry-feed-". any one know how I can do this. Thank you very much.

```
@ConsumeEvent("telemetry-feed-1" )
public void publishMatchingSubscriptions(String message) throws Exception {
   // process data
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@ConsumeEvent` annotation in Quarkus just makes the use of `io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus` easier and since the latter does not support regex, neither does the annotation

Comment: Thank you very much..  So, do we have any, another way to use this for "regex" or do I have to move for another solution instead of Vertx eventbus.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do what you want with the event bus